# C++ way to pass structured stuff?

Tags: c++, oop

Some people might find this question weird but I'll go ahead.

I have a class called Cxx for example.

I am porting something from C and do not have much experience in C++ : i am learning.
But basically, normally in C i had a struct :

```
typedef
struct cdata_s {
    int k;
    float g;
    char *z;
}
cdata_t;
```

I would like to pass an array of those structs to my constructor, for example

```
Cxx k(array_of_cdata, cdata_array_size);
```

I could also do

```
Cxx k(array_of_k, array_of_g, array_of_z, size); // i.e. no more structure, pass each member in array
```

I wonder though if all of this is good C++. After all, in the first method I use structs : structs are only in C++ for C compatibility right? It's not real C++ right?

And the second method is plain ugly.

What would be a good C++ way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: _'What would be a good C++ way to do this?'_ You should use a `std::array<cdata_s,ARRAY_SIZE>` or a `std::vector<cdata_s>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `structs` have real meaning in C++. The only difference between `structs` and `classes` are that all members of `structs` have default public access specifier. So your first method is fine, though using a `vector` is more convenient and idiomatic. And also, get rid of the C-like struct declarations.

```
struct cdata_s { //this is fine
    int k;
    float g;
    char *z;
}

Cxx k(vector<cdata_s> &vcs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using structs is fine. My only advice is to switch to vectors instead of arrays, as they can change their size of the fly, and keep track of their own size.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) . These store your data in different ways, vector <-> array, list <-> doubly linked list etc. They do all the boring stuff for you like keeping track of how many there are, allocations, clean up when the array goes out of scope etc.